# Mobile Website Development - Is there a difference between Operating System/Browsers?

Tags: php, mobile, web, mobile-website

I am working on a mobile website (m.website.com) and I am wondering if there is a need to differentiate between different operating systems or mobile browsers?

For example, I am using a mobile detecting PHP class from https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect and there are functions like isIOS() and isAndroid() or isChrome() and isSafari() as well as a general isMobile().

So the question is do I have to have different sets of webpages to accommodate different OS/browsers? Or all I have to do is to have a single set which falls under from the isMobile() function that all mobile OS/browsers will understand?

Comment: http://www.quicktips.in/how-to-detect-operating-system-using-php-in-webpage/

detect operating system using php

Answer (score -1):

You do not need different pages to target different OS/Browsers per se ... but that is only half the answer. Because the OS/Browsers have their own quirks, you have to code your pages in such a way that you code is compatible with "most" browsers/OS. An exercise known as cross browser compatible coding. If you do not do such coding, e.g. by picking up some specific features/bugs/non standard implementation of one particular OS/browser then your page might break in some other browsers.

Most 'modern' browsers are HTML standard compatible. The cross browser compat guidelines are mostly about sticking with HTML standard; that is if you are NOT targeting something like IE6.

Web has many articles on cross browser dev guidelines. e.g. see http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/cross-browser-compatible.htm

Answer (score -1):

Normally it's enough to use `isMobile` and create one template for all mobile devices.

You need isIOS, etc only, if you want to create different user experiences or use os dependent javascript functions/libraries. An example would be creating an mobile app, which looks like an native app and is available for iOS/Android/etc..